# LEFT JOIN mysql Filtrar registros não existentes NOT IN

Tags: mysql, data

boa tarde, o que estou tentando fazer é o seguinte:
tenho duas tabelas

**maquinas** - armazena os dados de localização da copiadora ( endereço, cep, etc ).

**leituras** - armazena o código da maquina, os contadores, dataleitura, etc

eu queria exibir **todos** os registros da tabela **MAQUINAS** **que não estivessem** na tabela leituras no periodo determinado;

não estou acertando fazer o JOIN, se eu colocar o intervalo, normalmente ele vai filtrar somente maquinas que estejam dentro daquele intervalo, mas eu quero o contrário. quero maquinas que não estejam naquele intervalo.

não estou conseguindo usar o **WHERE dataleitura NOT BETWEEN data1 AND data2**

```
SELECT maquinas.codigo, maquinas.codnovo
FROM leituras RIGHT JOIN maquinas
ON (leituras.CodigoMaquina = maquinas.Codigo)
where inativa=0
AND dataleitura>'2015-02-11' and dataleitura<'2015-03-17'
and codigodono=5
```

Quem puder dá uma força ai. Valeu

**Edição as 16:27:**
O que eu preciso, é listar TODAS as maquinas que NÃO tenha na tabela leituras no periodo especificado

**Edição as 16:48**
Isso aqui quase resolve o que eu quero, tou tentando usar um HAVING aqui pra ver se vai adequar.

```
SELECT maquinas.codigo, maquinas.codnovo, MAX(leituras.dataleitura) as ultLcto
FROM
maquinas INNER JOIN leituras ON maquinas.codigo=leituras.codigomaquina
WHERE inativa=0 AND codigodono=5
GROUP BY maquinas.codigo
ORDER BY codigomaquina
```

Comment: Para as duas datas que não estiverem entre o período tenta isso aqui: `WHERE dataleitura < CAST('2015-02-11' AS DATE)
OR dataleitura > CAST('2015-03-17' AS DATE)`

Comment: não entendi o uso do CAST nessa ocasião, essa função não é para conversão do tipo de dados ?

Comment: A proposta do Lucas não resolveu o que você precisava? Pelo que você fala, acredito que o que ele propôs resolveria.

Answer (score 2):

[Esta imagem](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg) pode ajudar. Nosso caso é o segundo da esquerda, de cima para baixo. Tenta o seguinte:

```
SELECT maquinas.codigo, maquinas.codnovo
FROM maquinas
LEFT JOIN leituras ON
    maquinas.Codigo = leituras.CodigoMaquina
    AND dataleitura > '2015-02-11' AND dataleitura < '2015-03-17'
WHERE leituras.CodigoMaquina IS NULL
AND inativa = 0    
AND codigodono = 5
```

Comment: O Registro não pode existir em dataleitura, veja a ultima edição que fiz no post. por esse motivo isso ai não funciona.  eu tenho que lista a maquina.codigo que não está dentro de leitura.

Comment: Você testou? O `WHERE leituras.CodigoMaquina IS NULL` é pra pegar os que não existem na outra tabela

Comment: vem em branco, mas existem maquinas lançadas nesse periodo

Comment: o registro não pode existir na tabela leituras. eu quero pegar maquinas.codigo que não tenha em leituras no intervalo que eu especifiquei ? tendeu ? veja minha ultima edição =)

Comment: Fiz uma alteração, veja se resolve